# Nuxt.js program not running on the Main Domain with Apache in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, apache, redirect, nuxt.js, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Nuxt.js program that I run on Apache in Ubuntu OS. When I port it to a subdomain like **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**, it works fine; But when I port it to the main domain such as **example.com**, my program does not run. Examples of Ubuntu Server and Apache settings are as follows:

***/etc/hostname***

```
example
```

***/etc/hosts***

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu
100.200.300.40  example.com
100.200.300.40  www.example.com
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

***/etc/resolv.conf***

```
nameserver 100.200.300.40
search example.com
```

***/etc/bind/named.conf.options***

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    
    forwarders {
        100.200.300.40;
        100.200.300.40;
    };
};
```

***/etc/bind/named.conf.local***

```
zone "example.com" IN {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
};

zone "300.200.100.in-addr.arpa" IN {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/db.100";
};
```

***/etc/bind/db.example.com***

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
            7
            7200
            900
            1209600
            86400 )
;
@   IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
@   IN  NS  ns2.example.com.
@   IN  A   100.200.300.40
@   IN  AAAA    ::1
ns1 IN  A   100.200.300.40
ns2 IN  A   100.200.300.40
www IN  A   100.200.300.40
```

***/etc/bind/db.100***

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
                  6     ; Serial
             7200       ; Refresh
              900       ; Retry
            1209600     ; Expire
             86400 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  ns1.
@   IN  NS  ns2.
@   IN  PTR ns1.example.com.
@   IN  PTR ns2.example.com.
```

***/etc/apache2/apache2.conf***

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

***/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

***/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com.conf***

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the question is how can I run the program on the main domain and redirect the address for example to **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** when someone goes to **example.com** address?

### Update

I already ported my Node.js program to the main domain through the following settings, which did not run:

***/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf***

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

And I even used the following two code examples to redirect from the main domain to the subdomain, which still did not work:

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You are mixing too many issues here, please read [ask]. Your DNS settings is not relevant. Just send the result of curl -i example.com and www.example.com, and details on your build, is it static or server?

Comment: This application runs on the server side. 
I just added all the information that different people might need in the face of the question; Because most people request different server settings to understand the question from the questioner. For this reason, I have included all the information that is usually requested by others in such questions, so that in addition to reading the question, they have access to the server, domain and Apache settings.

Comment: This information that I have entered, some people have asked me in the chat section of this website; So I've provided the information based on how different people think about this question. Also, I am very good at writing tips related to the question.

Comment: You have to elaborate about the "did not work" part...

Comment: Check this: https://serverfault.com/a/1055749/144563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I did not understand why **Nuxt.js** does not run on the main domain, at least with **Apache** on the **Ubuntu** OS.*
But by writing a proper ***Redirect Rule***, I was able to solve this problem which is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{SERVER_NAME} =http://example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{SERVER_NAME} =http://www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

If someone wanted to run the project on HTTPS, the process is as follows (SSL license in the following example is ***Let's Encrypt Free SSL Wildcard Certificate***; for more information about it, you can refer to [this](https://lakin-mohapatra.medium.com/generate-lets-encrypt-free-wildcard-certificate-on-ubuntu-18-dcf26f458e13) web page):

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{SERVER_NAME} =http://example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{SERVER_NAME} =http://www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost www.example.com:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{SERVER_NAME} =https://example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```